# Why is the assistant still show Malformed response despite having conv.close?

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google

Despite using the conv.close tag, the error 'Malformed_Response' is still shown.
Here is the code:

```
app.intent('Selected subjects', (conv, {Subject}) => {
  var subject = conv.arguments.get('OPTION') || Subject;
  if (!conv.screen) {
    conv.ask(subjectCard[subject].text);
  } else {
    conv.ask(new BasicCard(subjectCard[subject]));
  }
  conv.ask(' Do you want to hear about a new subject?');
  conv.ask(new Suggestions('Yes', 'No'));
});


app.intent(['Selected subjects - yes'], (conv) => {
  var subject = conv.arguments.get('OPTION') || Subject;
  if (!conv.screen) {
    conv.close(subjectCard[subject].text);
  } else {
    conv.close(`Maybe this would help`, new BasicCard(subjectCard[subject]));
  }
});
```

The pictures of firebase errors are attached.

Thanks in advance[image: the first error regarding this piece of code.]
[image: Full Thing]

This is the request:

```
{
"response": "Team Edzuki isn't responding right now. Try again soon.",
"expectUserResponse": false,
"conversationToken": "GidzaW11bG...",
"audioResponse": "//NExAASWK...",
"sharedDebugInfoList": [
  {
    "name": "ResponseValidation",
    "debugInfo": "",
    "subDebugEntryList": [
      {
        "name": "MalformedResponse",
        "debugInfo": "'final_response' must be set.",
        "subDebugEntryList": []
      }
    ]
  }
  ]
  },
  "visualResponse": {
  "visualElementsList": [
  {
    "displayText": {
      "content": "Team Edzuki isn't responding right now. Try again 
    soon."
    }
    }
    ],
    "suggestionsList": [],
    "agentLogoUrl": ""
    },
    "clientError": 0,
    "is3pResponse": 1
    }
```

This is part of the debug tag seen in the Action-On-Google webpage, and the error I have mentioned above, with the picture of the firebase tab health, is the error that is being repeated. No other error is being shown. If anybody has a different way of using the follow-up prompts, please do tell.

Comment: If you are getting an error it would also help if you updated your question to include the contents of the "request", "results", "error", and "debug" tabs from the simulator, since they provide a great deal of information to help debug

Comment: No secondary error except of Malformed_response is visible

Comment: I didn't say "secondary error". I said "debugging information". All those tabs provide information that can help diagnose the issue.

Comment: I've added the necessary error onto the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is extremely simple: the intent is built so every time you say the correct words, the action/ intent will work. So, in this case at least, the easiest way is to set the Selected subjects - yes to a text response, to make it work as log as you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

The portion of the error message in the Response that you posted that says "Webhook call failed. Error: 500 Internal Server Error" suggests that there is a problem with your code that is causing the code to crash.

Check your Firebase logs for where and what the error might be. But some possibilities include:

First, in the "Selected subjects" intent handler, you are calling both `conv.close()` and `conv.ask()`. Given you're trying to close the conversation, it isn't clear why you're doing it this way.

The error message from your logs about "Subject is not defined" appears to be because in your second intent (the one that appears to be called when it crashes), although you use `Subject` in the function (when you assign possibly it to `subject`), it isn't in the list of parameters that are available. (You had a problem with `Subject` vs `subject` before, but this isn't quite the same issue.)

To be even more clear, the code should be something like

```
app.intent('Selected subjects - yes', (conv, {Subject}) => {
  var subject = conv.arguments.get('OPTION') || Subject;
  if (!conv.screen) {
    conv.close(subjectCard[subject].text);
  } else {
    conv.close(`Maybe this would help`, new BasicCard(subjectCard[subject]));
  }
});
```

Finally, it isn't clear under what conditions the error about "a simple response is required" is generated, but it seems possible that you're trying to send a Basic Card without any simple text, or possibly that it is expecting the text *before* the Basic Card in your "Selected subjects" intent handler.

Comment: I tried the edits you suggested, but the same error is being thrown. Also, the simple response was a one off error, so its no longer relevant

Comment: See update about Subject in the parameters of the second handler.

Comment: My mistake, but still no result. Still Malformed response: Final_response must be set

Comment: Please update the question with the text values of the "request", "response", "debug", and "error" tabs from the simulator when you get the error. It would also be useful to know which handler is being called, and exactly which conditions are being evaluated, when you're getting that error.

Comment: I've added above the response and what I was trying to do. I can't make heads or tails of it, but maybe you will be able to

Comment: Yes, it helped a great deal, although posting it as text rather than an image would have helped further. Posting the other tabs *as text* might also help further. Answer is updated.

Comment: This edit still does not enable the error to stop, but the same error, the one above, is shown on firebase